# Why I don't have access to my AAD app registration in Azure Portal, but I can view it using Azure CLI?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-cli, azureportal

I can register my app using `az ad app create` or using old portal https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/#/appList in my company's AAD, and I can review it using `az ad app view`

Now in Azure portal I can't view it.

[image: Azure Portal Screenshot]

It's understandable, that I don't have access to the Azure Active Directory pane in Azure Portal, but even when I copy&paste azure portal link directly to my app registration, it still says I don't have access to view it.

Why? Is it a bug in Azure Portal? What permission do I need in order to use Azure Portal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a bug, I can reproduce your issue on my side. Your tenant may set the `Restrict access to Azure AD administration portal` to `Yes` in `User settings`.

[image]

With the setting to `Yes`, the non-admin user will not be able to access the Azure AD admin portal, but the other client like PowerShell, CLI will work.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

To fix the issue, you have two options.

1.Ask the `Global admin` of your tenant to give you an [Administrator role](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/users-groups-roles/directory-assign-admin-roles), navigate to the `Azure Active Directory` in the portal -> `Roles and administrators` -> choose a role, click `Add assignment` -> add your account.

2.Ask the `Global admin` of your tenant to set the `Restrict access to Azure AD administration portal` setting to `No`.